# Changing FPS of a video to 1 FPS, how to guarantee at least 1 frame?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been converting videos with `ffmpeg` to 1 FPS using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i Example1.gif -c:v libaom-av1 -filter:v "fps=1" test1.webm
```

However this has no output for very short videos, e.g. a gif that is 0.2s long and only has two frames. Is there a way to force ffmpeg to select at least one frame? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is related to the default rounding method of `fps` filter.

Executing `ffmpeg -h filter=fps`shows that the default rounding method is "near".
That means that frames with timestamps < 0.5sec are rounded to zero, when fps=1.

I am not sure about it, but I think the first frame to be encoded is frame with timestamp >= 0.5sec when fps=1 (`fps` filter is looking for the center of the frame duration).
That means that when using `fps=1`, clips with duration less than 0.5 seconds are going to be empty.

We may fix this behaviour by setting `round=up`:

`ffmpeg -y -i Example1.gif -c:v libaom-av1 -filter:v "fps=1:round=up" test1.webm`

Other option is using `-r 1` instead of using `fps` filter:

`ffmpeg -y -i Example1.gif -c:v libaom-av1 -r 1 test1.webm`

---

The downside of the above solutions is that the first output frame is going to be the first input frame instead of the center of the first second.
We may think of implementing a short script that checks the input duration before executing FFmpeg, and select the arguments accordingly.

---

For testing we may generate GIF with duration of 0.4 seconds as follows:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -r 10 -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=N/10/TB,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" Example1.gif`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and suggestionds, Rotem! I've tested with `round=up` and it works perfectly. I'd actually like to use your trick with a negative `-ss` as well but that seems to fail for gifs with "could not seek to position -0.163". This seems to work fine for other media types though, e.g. mp4

Comment: You are right, `"fps=1:start_time=0.5"` is not working with GIF input. I prepared `Example1.gif` for testing, but tested with `Example1.mp4` by mistake. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the subject of the post
[ffmpeg-python outputs black screen when trying to save as mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080205/ffmpeg-python-outputs-black-screen-when-trying-to-save-as-mp4).

The answer by llogan says :

> **Your player does not like 1 fps**
>
> Many players behave similarly.
>
> You can still provide a low frame rate for the input, but give a more
> normal frame rate for the output. `ffmpeg` will simply duplicate the
> frames. The output video won't look different than your original
> command, but it will play.
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i "pics2/Image%02d.png" -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p Output.mp4
> ```